# Can subset sum algorithm be modified for a set of single digit numbers?

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

The subset sum algorithm tries to find a subset adding up to a specified value, for instance, X = 30. But what if my set only ever includes single digits, i.e. 1-9, where an example set (sorted) could be

```
S = {1,1,1,3,4,5,6,9,9,9,9}.
```

Then can I run a modified subset sum which would always run in polynomial time? I have considered that instead of:

```
if lastNum > X
    removing lastNum from S
```

I can remove all numbers, i, where i*`num_i_in_set` > X. For example, in pseudocode:

```
count = 1
if num == previousNum 
     count++ // for 9, this will get up to 4
if num*count > X // 
    remove num // remove one of the digits, also removes any num > X
    count = 0 
...
```

if i equals 9, there are four 9's, 9 times 4 greater than 30, so I can remove one of the 9's and reduce the size of my set. I cannot see how this would improve performance over the traditional subset sum algorithm. I want to say my time complexity would add up to O(n^9), which seems extremely high. Am I overthinking this problem, or is there no way to change subset sum for single digits only?

Comment: The reduction you're suggesting is sound, and it should be possible to do it in linear time if the input is already sorted -- just mark each number that you want to remove in a first pass, and then remove all marked numbers in a second pass.  (But don't reset `count` to 0 when you mark a count -- that should be in an `else` branch attached to your first `if`.)  Every number removed will speed up the usual brute-force algorithm, but it won't change the asymptotic time complexity since X can be big enough that it never applies.

Comment: Also have a look at the Wikipedia page -- there's a dynamic programming algorithm that takes time and space proportional to the *value* of X times the number of elements in S.  This is technically not polynomial time but pseudopolynomial time (because it's exponential in log(X), which is the number of bits needed to express X), but it's a neat algorithm and very often fast enough anyway.

Comment: Convrt your array to 9 buckets (the counts for each digit 1-9) int[] buckets = new int[9]; for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) buckets[(list[i] - 1)]++;  then run a dp solution against the buckets for sum=30 it would be 3*3*4*5*6*7*10*15*30 complexity Floor(sum / digit_9) * ... * Floor(sum / digit_1)